# Pseudo-Indent (two spaces) Multiple Lines

Tags: indentation

Basically, I need to indent a block of R code. Unfortunately, vim's tab size is bigger than the two spaces that I'm using. Is it possible to accomplish this without hitting the space bar twice for every line I need to indent?

The motivation for this may be of note: I originally wrote the script in Rstudio before moving it to a server. Many indents just go away when I edit the server-side file with vim. However, if I transfer the file to my laptop (via winSCP) and open it in rstudio, all the indents look perfect!

Comment: why don't you change the `tabstop` and `shiftwidth` options?

Comment: that would probably work, but not the best solution since I only want to change it for .R files specifically (since I use vim to edit other types of code too)

Comment: @MikePalmice To follow Mass's suggestion you can create `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/r.vim` containing `setlocal tabstop=X` which will change the value only for the buffers with the filetype `r` (Also [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/wiki/tabstop) is worth reading before modifying `tabstop`)

Comment: @statox thanks! if you want to paste into an answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you probably want to set `tabstop` and `shiftwidth` to `2` to have the indentation work as you want.

Now you want these settings applied only for the files with the filetype `r`, the best way to do that is to create a custom `ftplugin`. To do that you want to create the file `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/r.vim`.

This file will be sourced when the filetype of a buffer is set to `r` and after the `ftplugin` which comes with Vim by default has been sourced (this way you don't loose the already existing settings).

In this file you can simply add:

```
setlocal tabstop=2
setlocal shiftwidth=2
```

Here you need to use `setlocal` instead of `set` to make sure that the settings will only apply to the current buffer and not to all buffers.

Some interesting related help topics:

- [`:h ftplugin`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_41.txt.html#ftplugin)
- [`:h :setlocal`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%3asetlocal)
- [`:h 'shiftwidth'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27shiftwidth%27)
- [`:h 'tabstop'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27tabstop%27)

And a good read about indentation settings in Vim: [/r/vim wiki](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/wiki/tabstop)

Comment: If OP is working with spaces instead of tabs, it’s generally preferable to leave `tabstop` at 8, and set `shiftwidth` *and* `softtabstop` to the same (eg 2). Then you’ll want `expandtab` as well. Otherwise youre using hard tabs that are made to look like 2 spaces.

Comment: Just noted OP says « pseudo indent »...